# Protractor Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, protractor, e2e-testing

When selecting an item from the list gets a timeout. The item is selected, but the test ends with an error message. Does anyone know what I should change?

app.e2e-spec.ts

```
it('applications - select item from list', () => {
 page.scroolPageDown();
 page.clickLastPage();
 page.selectItemFromList();
 page.scroolPage();
});
```

app.po.ts

```
selectItemFromList() {
 return element
  .all(by.css('.list-item .item-body'))
  .last()
  .click();
}
```

Comment: did you read the link they provide in the error message?  should have been this: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md

Answer (score 1):

Add more time to default timeout interval in conf.js file. In my tests I have this value:

```
defaultTimeoutInterval: 200000,
```